# Error when calling a method with command line argument

Tags: ruby

I want to pass a command line argument to my program and then  reference the argument in a method I'm calling but I'm receiving the `undefined local variable or method error player_name`.

I'm very new to Ruby, so this might be a basic question but I try to understand how to use ARGV properly. 
Is it not possible to use the input the user provides as a command line argument in a method and then call this method? What am I missing?

```
player_name = ARGV.first

def start
    puts "Hey #{player_name}, do you want to go left or right?"
    print "> "
end

start
```

Comment: For sure using @player_name or PLAYER_NAME would work

Comment: If you have to use a local variable in method, you can pass it as a method argument. `def start(player_name)` and than `start(player_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `ARGV` is correct. Simply `player_name` is not defined in the `start` method. If you want to keep your method pass to it the variable

```
def start(player_name)
  puts "Hey #{player_name}, do you want to go left or right?"
  print "> "
end

first_argument = ARGV.first
start(first_argument)
```

Note: I changed a variable name and moved a line to show you that they're not the same variables. You're passing it around. I think it's clearer now

Comment: My pleasure @astarisborn :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer checkout this explanation of variable scopes in ruby: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ruby-variable-scope/